# Jackson: JsonIdentityInfo serialises depth of only one child

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, jackson2

For some reason JsonIdentityInfo serialises the depth of one child but not the other. My example:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
class A {
  private long id;
  private B last;

  // Getters, setters...
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
class B {
  private long id;
  private A a;
  private C c1;
  private C c2;

  // Getters, setters...
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")
class C {
  private long id;
  private Set<A> as;
  private B last;

  // Getters, setters...
}
```

I serialise object `B` it serialises child `A a` to some depth, serialises `C c1` to few levels deep. But `C c2` only gets the reference.

I want `A a; C c1; C c2;` serialised only to first depth or also include `c2` regardless of depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation on the property `c1` and `c2` in class `B`. i.e.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = 
ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "id")

class B {
  private long id;
  private A a;
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private C c1;
  @JsonUnwrapped
  private C c2;

  // Getters, setters...
}
```